# Repeat through bash script based on user input

Tags: bash, loops, shell, if-statement

```
#sets dir name 
echo "What is the name of the target?"
read targetName

#changes dir to desktop
mkdir -p ../Desktop/Notes
cd ../Desktop/Notes

#make working directory
mkdir $targetName
cd $targetName
mkdir "IPs" "SubDomains" "Screenshots" "NmapScans" "Notes"
```

I have been trying to wrap my brain around simple loops in bash. I have the following script I would like to ask a user for "targetName" to create some directories. After the directories are created I would like the script to ask the user if they would like to create another target, If Y/Yes loop back, if no then exit. I realize this is a fairly simple issue, new to bash and programming in general and I work best if I create the problem myself. Im 99% sure I need a if loop for this. Im just not sure how to break it up correctly. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that helps you:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    IFS= read -p 'What is the name of the target? ' -r targetName

    # sanity checks:
    # * no empty input
    # * no '/' in input
    if [ ${#targetName} -eq 0 ] || [[ ${targetName} == */* ]]
    then
        echo 'error: invalid target name' 1>&2
        continue
    fi

    # for now, just print what you'll be doing
    printf 'mkdir -p \\\n'
    printf '  %q \\\n' ~/Desktop/Notes/"$targetName"/{IPs,SubDomains,Screenshots,NmapScans,Notes}

    read -p 'Do you wish to create an other target?[y/n] ' -n 1 yesno
    echo

    case "$yesno" in
        [Yy]) continue;;
        *) break;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I see a few commands that I am not very familiar with that seem to have done the trick.